# Install GraphicsMagick on Google Cloud VM Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, graphicsmagick

I have a `Google Cloud Compute Engine` instance running for my `Discord Bot` server. It is an `E2-micro` instance running `Linux/Debian`.

I would like to install `GraphicsMagick` on the instance so it is available for the Node.JS app I am running. I heard that `ImageMagick` was installed by default on Google Cloud, but that doesn't seem to be the case anymore. I read you could use it in Cloud Functions and the like.

I have no experience installing binaries on a cloud server, so I'm unsure how to approach it.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphicsMagick can be installed in all currently supported versions of Debian by running the following command.

```
sudo apt install graphicsmagick
```

The following  GraphicsMagick packages can also be installed from the default Debian repositories in bullseye and bookworm.

graphicsmagick-dbg
  graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
  graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
  libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12
  libgraphicsmagick++1-dev
  libgraphicsmagick-q16-3
  libgraphicsmagick1-dev

Answer (score 1):

As per this official [doc](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-unix.html):

> GraphicsMagick may be compiled from source code for virtually any
> modern Unix system (including Linux and MacOS X) and Microsoft
> Windows. Installation instructions may be found in the following
> files.
>
> GraphicsMagick is distributed in a number of different archive
> formats. The source code must be extracted prior to compilation as
> follows:
>
> For example:
>
> PK-ZIP archive format. Requires that the unzip program from
> Info-Zip(http://www.info-zip.org/UnZip.html) be available. Extract
> similar to:
>
> ```
> unzip GraphicsMagick-1.3.zip
> ```
>
> The GraphicsMagick source code is extracted into a subdirectory
> similar to 'GraphicsMagick-1.3'. After the source code extracted,
> change to the new directory (using the actual directory name) using a
> command similar to:
>
> ```
> cd GraphicsMagick-1.3
> ```
>
> Use 'configure' to automatically configure, build, and install
> GraphicsMagick. The configure script may be executed from the
> GraphicsMagick source directory (e.g ./configure) or from a separate
> build directory by specifying the full path to configure
>
> The advantage of using a separate build directory is that multiple
> GraphicsMagick builds may share the same GraphicsMagick source
> directory while allowing each build to use a unique set of options.
> Using a separate directory also makes it easier to keep track of any
> files you may have edited.
>
> If you are willing to accept configure's default options (static
> build, 8 bits/sample), and build from within the source directory,
> type:
>
> ```
> ./configure
> ```
>
> If you are not happy with configure's choice of compiler, compilation
> flags, or libraries, you can give 'configure' initial values for
> variables by specifying them on the configure command line, e.g.:
>
> .
>
> ```
> /configure CC=c99 CFLAGS=-O2 LIBS=-lposix
> ```
>
> Options which should be common to packages installed under the same
> directory heirarchy may be supplied via a 'config.site' file located
> under the installation prefix via the path ${prefix}/share/config.site
> where ${prefix} is the installation prefix
>
> As an alternative, the CONFIG_SITE environment variable may be used to
> specify the path of a site configuration file to load. This is an
> example config.site file:
>
> ```
> # Configuration values for all packages installed under this prefix
> CC=gcc
> CXX=c++
> CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/include'
> LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib'
> ```
>
> When the 'config.site' file is being used to supply configuration
> options, configure will issue a message similar to:
>
> ```
> configure: loading site script /usr/local/share/config.site
> ```
>
> You can enable optional features, Optional Packages/Options, build and
> install  by following above doc